# How can I tell if a node js net socket is transferring data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a game that will connect to many clients over the web socket protocol. Sometimes the internet bandwidth is not large enough to transfer all the data. I need some way of telling if a net socket is transferring data, so that I can drop frames instead of the messages building up in the web socket. I am using the websocket library and it also allows access the the net module sockets it used.

Comment: If you're using `socket.io` you can use `socket.volatile.emit` to send messages that can be automatically dropped.

Comment: We really need to know what library you are using.

Comment: @MikeC I'm pretty sure the implication is they're _not_ using the built-in `net` module... _"I am using the websocket library and it also allows access the the net module sockets it used."_

Comment: @jcollum my guess is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right. I missed that line.